# Android studio showing out of memory and asking to increase the size. It is getting when I open one of the xml resource file

Tags: android, spinner, heap-memory

I used 20 spinners and 40 textviews for displaying the name poster. When I edit this xml resource file Android Studio showing popup is Out of memory error
    [Here is the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntQWg.png)

I incresed the xmx size to 2048.
    Eventhogh it showing same error when I open that xml file. here I put the xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>      
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adViewContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.85">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relNameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner2"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner3"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner4"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner5"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner4"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner5"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/spinner7"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner6"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner6"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner6"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner7"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner6"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner6"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner7"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner6"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner6"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner7"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner7"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner7"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner7"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner7"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner8"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner8"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner9"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/spinner11"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner8"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner8"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner9"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner9"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner10"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner10"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner11"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/spinner13"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner12"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner12"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner12"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner11"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner11"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner11"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner11"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner11"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner12"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner12"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner13"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/spinner15"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner12"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner12"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner13"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner15"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner13"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner13"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner13"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner13"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner13"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner14"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner14"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner15"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner14"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner14"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner15"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner17"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner15"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner15"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner15"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner15"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner15"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner16"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner16"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner17"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner16"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner18"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner16"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner16"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner17"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSpinner16"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner19"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner17"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner17"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner17"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner17"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner17"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner20"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner18"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner18"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner19"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner18"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner20"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner18"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner18"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner19"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSpinner18"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner19"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner19"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner19"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner19"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner19"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner20"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner20"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner21"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner20"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner20"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner20"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner21"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSpinner20"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner23"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner21"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner21"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner21"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner21"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner21"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner24"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner22"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner22"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner23"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner22"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner24"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner22"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner22"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner23"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSpinner22"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner25"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner23"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner23"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner23"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner23"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner23"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner26"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner24"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner24"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner25"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner24"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner26"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner24"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner24"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner25"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSpinner24"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner27"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner25"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner25"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner25"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner25"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner25"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner28"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner26"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner26"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner27"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner26"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSpinner28"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner26"

            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner26"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner27"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSpinner26"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#0287FC"

            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spinner29"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner27"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner27"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner27"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner27"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner27"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"

            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner30"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner28"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner28"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner29"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner28"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

         .........
         ..........
         .........




    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I used 20 spinners and 40 textviews layout to display a poster as following shown. Is there any other way to get that please do let me know.

[My poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fllSR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this problem today for a few hours and ended up trying File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... and chose the Invalidate/Restart option. Seems to have fixed the Out of Memory error.

Don't know if that will work for you at a later time, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: I had done that too. still same problem when I open or edit that xml file. I tried open that file in other android studio, It showing same error.